# Circles of text

Tags: code-challenge, ascii-art

Find a way to make circles of a given radius using characters in a console. Please specify the font name and size. Also, please provide at least one example of the output.

For example:

**Input:**

```
3
```

**Output:**

```
   ******
 **      **
**        **
*          *
**        **
 **      **
   ******
```

...Well, something better looking than that "hand drawn" "circle" with a radius of 3.

---

**Bonus question:** Ellipses. :)

Comment: Interestingly enough, my radius-3 circle is exactly identical to yours without even trying :)

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440314/code-golf-day

Comment: Maybe the font-part can be clarified. Copied here, all fonts will be the same; the same for font-size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Javascript (360)

```
function c(r){var f=1.83;var e=2*Math.PI/(r*r*r*r*r);var s=r*2+1;var g=Array(s);for(var i=0;i<s;i++){g[i]=Array(Math.round(s*f))};for(var i=0;i<=2*Math.PI;i+=e) {var x=Math.round(f*r*Math.cos(i)+f*r);var y=Math.round(r*Math.sin(i))+r;g[y][x]=1;}for(var j=0;j<g.length;j++){for(var i=0;i<g[j].length;i++)document.write((g[j][i]==1)?'*':' ');document.writeln()}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YssSb/3/ (`f` is a correction factor for the line-height / font-width ratio.  If you use a square font setting, i.e., set line-height = font-size, you can set f=1 and get "square" circles. Or set `f` arbitrarily for ellipses.)

Output for 3 (interestingly enough, accidentally exactly the same shape as OP), 5, 15:

```
   ******    
 **      **  
**        ** 
*          * 
**        ** 
 **      **  
   ******    

     *********      
   ***       ****   
 ***            **  
**               ** 
*                 * 
*                 * 
*                 * 
**               ** 
 ***            **  
   ***       ****   
     *********      

                    ***************                      
               ******             ******                 
            ****                       *****             
          ***                              ***           
        ***                                  ***         
      ***                                      ***       
     **                                          **      
    **                                            **     
   **                                              **    
  **                                                **   
 **                                                  **  
 *                                                    *  
**                                                    ** 
*                                                      * 
*                                                      * 
*                                                      * 
*                                                      * 
*                                                      * 
**                                                    ** 
 *                                                    *  
 **                                                  **  
  **                                                **   
   **                                              **    
    **                                            **     
     **                                          **      
      ***                                      ***       
        ***                                  ***         
          ***                              ***           
            ****                       *****             
               ******             ******                 
                    ***************
```

Comment: Nice looking circles you've got. ;)

Answer (score 6):

#### a Bresenham circle in Scala (35)

The Bresenham - algorithm has 2 major points:

- works without sin/ cosin.
- you only calculate ¼*½ circle, the other points are found by mirroring.

How to do it:

```
       2 1  
     DCBABCD
   GFE  |  EFG
  IJ   y|----JI
 GJ     |    /JG
 F      |   / |F
DE      | r/  |ED
C       | /   | C
B 4     |/    | B 3
A       +-------A
B 4'          x B 3'
C               C
DE             ED
 F             F
 GJ           JG
  IJ         JI
   GFE     EFG
     DCBABCD
       2'1'
```

- We only calculate the numbers from A in the zenit to I.

  - Point I is at 45°, defined by x == y.
  - Ground zero is where the + is.
  - The A in the zenit is the point (x=0, y=r), r = radius.
  - To draw a closed circle we move clockwise (++x), which is to the right (x+=1) or down to the next point, (y-=1).
  - every point(x,y) on the circle is r away from the center.
    Pythagoras says, r²=x²+y².
  - This smells like square-root and equitations with 2 solutions, but beware!
  - we start at A and want to know, whether we paint next the  point below or the point beneath to the right.
- we calculate for both points (x²+y²) and build for both the  difference to r² (which stays of course constant).

  - since the difference can be negative, we take the abs from it.
  - then we look which point is closer to the result (r²), eo ipso smaller.
  - depending on that we draw the right or bottom neighbor.
- the so found point

  - 1 x, y gets mirrored
  - 2 -x, y to the left
  - 3 y, x at the diagonal
  - 4 -y, x from there to the left
- all those points get mirrored again to the south

  - 1' x, -y
  - 2' -x, -y
  - 3' y, -x
  - 4' -y, -x done.

This isn't code golf, but all those numbers at the top of the existing solutions made me think it is, so I spent useless time in golfing my solution. Therefore I added a useless number at the top too. It's 11 times Pi rounded.

```
object BresenhamCircle extends App {
    var count = 0
    val r = args(0).toInt
    // ratio > 1 means expansion in horizontal direction
    val ratio = args(1).toInt
    val field = ((0 to 2 * r).map (i=> (0 to 2 * r * ratio).map (j=> ' ').toArray)).toArray
    def square (x: Int, y: Int): Int = x * x + y * y
    def setPoint (x: Int, y: Int) {
        field (x)(y*ratio) = "Bresenham"(count)
        field (y)(x*ratio) = "Bresenham"(count)
    }
    def points (x: Int, y: Int)
    {
        setPoint (r + x, r + y)
        setPoint (r - x, r + y)
        setPoint (r + x, r - y)
        setPoint (r - x, r - y)
    }
    def bresenwalk () {
        var x = 0;
        var y = r;
        val rxr = r * r
        points (x, y);
        do 
        {
            val (dx, dy) = { if (math.abs (rxr - square ((x+1), y)) < math.abs (rxr - square (x, (y-1))))
                (1, 0)
            else
                (0, -1) 
            }
            count = (count + 1) % "Bresenham".length
            x += dx
            y += dy
            points (x, y)
        }while ((x <= y))
    }
    bresenwalk ()
    println (field.map (_.mkString ("")).mkString ("\n"))
}
```

The font-question is decided by sites webserver and your browser settings. Now, that I'm looking it is

```
'Droid Sans Mono',Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,serif
```

Font-size is 12px. Pretty useless information, if you ask me, but who does?

Bonus: ellipses and sample output:

The invocation is

```
    scala BresenhamCircle SIZE RATIO
```

for example

```
    scala BresenhamCircle 10 2
              s e r B r e s              
          h n e           e n h          
      e m a                   a m e      
    e r                           r e    
    m                               m    
  h a                               a h  
  n                                   n  
s e                                   e s
e                                       e
r                                       r
B                                       B
r                                       r
e                                       e
s e                                   e s
  n                                   n  
  h a                               a h  
    m                               m    
    e r                           r e    
      e m a                   a m e      
          h n e           e n h          
              s e r B r e s           

A ratio of 2 will print a circular shape for most fonts which happen to be about twice as tall than wide. To compensate for that, we widen by 2. 
# As smaller value than 2 only 1 is available: 

scala BresenhamCircle 6 1
    erBre    
  aes   sea  
 ah       ha 
 e         e 
es         se
r           r
B           B
r           r
es         se
 e         e 
 ah       ha 
  aes   sea  
    erBre    

# widening it has more freedom:

scala BresenhamCircle 12 5
                                             s    e    r    B    r    e    s                                             
                              a    h    n    e                             e    n    h    a                              
                         B    m                                                           m    B                         
                    e    r                                                                     r    e                    
               e    s                                                                               s    e               
          B    r                                                                                         r    B          
     a    m                                                                                                   m    a     
     h                                                                                                             h     
     n                                                                                                             n     
s    e                                                                                                             e    s
e                                                                                                                       e
r                                                                                                                       r
B                                                                                                                       B
r                                                                                                                       r
e                                                                                                                       e
s    e                                                                                                             e    s
     n                                                                                                             n     
     h                                                                                                             h     
     a    m                                                                                                   m    a     
          B    r                                                                                         r    B          
               e    s                                                                               s    e               
                    e    r                                                                     r    e                    
                         B    m                                                           m    B                         
                              a    h    n    e                             e    n    h    a                              
                                             s    e    r    B    r    e    s
```

I restricted the ratio parameter for Int to keep it simple, but it can easily be widened to allow floats.

Comment: your character count (without unneeded newlines) is in fact 34.557519189487725623089077216075 :)  BTW: very nice solution, +1

Answer (score 4):

### Python (172)

172 chars including the two mandatory newlines. Uses the Bresenham algorithm for conic curves (no divisions or multiplications); it only outputs circles for square fonts, but should be exempt from staircase effects (*ie.* always has the same width).

```
y=input();t=[y*[' ']for x in range(y)];x=0;y-=1;p=3-2*y
while x<=y:t[x][y]=t[y][x]='*';n,y=((x-y+1,y-1),(x,y))[p<0];p+=4*n+6;x+=1
for s in t[::-1]+t:print"".join(s[::-1]+s)
```

Not very pretty, but well, I thought I'd give it a shot.

```
  ****
 *    *
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
 *    *
  ****

          ********
       ***        ***
      *              *
     *                *
    *                  *
   *                    *
  *                      *
 *                        *
 *                        *
 *                        *
*                          *
*                          *
*                          *
*                          *
*                          *
*                          *
*                          *
*                          *
 *                        *
 *                        *
 *                        *
  *                      *
   *                    *
    *                  *
     *                *
      *              *
       ***        ***
          ********
```

**Edit**: typo, replaced *addition* with *division*.

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 180 characters

This code makes circles if the font is square.  It's pretty easy to modify to generate nominal ellipses if you know your font height/width ratio.

```
import math
r=input()
d=2*r+1
c=[' '*d]*d
for a in xrange(9*d):f=math.pi*a/r/9; x=int(r+r*math.sin(f)+.5);y=int(r+r*math.cos(f)+.5);c[y]=c[y][:x]+'*'+c[y][x+1:]
for s in c:print s
```

Examples:

```
4:
  *****  
 **   ** 
**     **
*       *
*       *
*       *
**     **
 **   ** 
  *****  

7:
     *****     
   **     **   
  **       **  
 **         ** 
**           **
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
**           **
 **         ** 
  **       **  
   **     **   
     *****
```

Comment: Could you post a sample?

Comment: +1 But 2nd place... It was close, though.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl (92)

I went for the “bonus question” and made it exploit the character aspect ratio to draw ellipses :)

```
($w)=@ARGV;for$x(-$w..$w){$p.=abs($x*$x+$_*$_-$w*$w)<$w?'*':$"for(-$w..$w);$p.=$/;}print $p;
```

Example outputs:

```
>perl circle.pl 3
  ***
 *   *
*     *
*     *
*     *
 *   *
  ***

>perl circle.pl 5
   *****
  *     *
 *       *
*         *
*         *
*         *
*         *
*         *
 *       *
  *     *
   *****

>perl circle.pl 8
      *****
    **     **
   *         *
  *           *
 *             *
 *             *
*               *
*               *
*               *
*               *
*               *
 *             *
 *             *
  *           *
   *         *
    **     **
      *****
```

Comment: +1 3rd place, but the shapes don't look as nice as in the other answers. (Still better than what I could program, of course. :) )

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell (<s>112</s> 109)

```
g n=map(zipWith(?)f.repeat)f where x?y|abs(x^2+y^2-n^2)<n='*'|0<1=' ';f=[-n..n]
main=interact$unlines.g.read
```

This works by checking, whether x² + y² - r² < n for all points. All points for which this is true are stars, all others are blanks.

#### Examples:

```
$ echo 3 | runhaskell circ.hs 
  ***  
 *   * 
*     *
*     *
*     *
 *   * 
  ***  
$ echo 10 | runhaskell circ.hs 
       *******       
     **       **     
    *           *    
   *             *   
  *               *  
 *                 * 
 *                 * 
*                   *
*                   *
*                   *
*                   *
*                   *
*                   *
*                   *
 *                 * 
 *                 * 
  *               *  
   *             *   
    *           *    
     **       **     
       *******
```

See here for big example: http://www.ideone.com/t042u

Answer (score 0):

## C, 127 Bytes, Font name: Arial Super Bold

```
#include<math.h>
main(){int r=10,c=r*2+1,q=c*c,d;for(;q--;)d=hypot(r-q%c,r-q/c),printf("%c%s",d>r-4&&d<=r?42:32,q%c?"":"\n");}
```

Result:

```
      *********      
    *************    
   ***************   
  *****************  
 ******       ****** 
 *****         ***** 
*****           *****
****             ****
****             ****
****             ****
****             ****
****             ****
****             ****
****             ****
*****           *****
 *****         ***** 
 ******       ****** 
  *****************  
   ***************   
    *************    
      *********
```

Comment: [110 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQl1SY3sSRDL8OOK02jSLM6Lb9IIzOvRCHZtki3rkin0DZZK1knxbpQV9e6vCizJFXDUMdH6cGKVQ9WLFDS1kixKdI1rkmxK9LUKVRNtje0MtLUTLHNqCzIL9Eo0gUK6QBJ/WRN69r/uYmZeRpA8zUMDUDcf8lpOYnpxf91c3IB "C (gcc) – Try It Online")